# Office 365 invite someone through his/her gmail

Tags: office-365

I try to invite someone with his/her gmail but it always want me to type an neccessary value. How can I add someone through the gmail acount?

Comment: what do you mean by "necessarry value"?

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge you could only invite either Microsoft accounts or Office 365 users. This also means that you might need to associated you email address with an Office account prior to be able invite that user http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/office365-sharepoint-online-small-business-help/redir/XT101810845.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HA101850586